# Page doesn't work in server

Tags: javascript, php, json, dom, localhost

I create a Statistics page with javascript/php when I try it in my localhost it's work without any problem

but when I make it in an on ligne server

Microsoft Edge give me this result : HTTP 500 error

That's odd... Microsoft Edge can’t find this page

And Firefox give me a white page

why ?!!

You can show the result here :

> http://hipponeimmo.com/test/charts.php

the error_log said :

> [10-Jul-2016 17:03:28 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/hipponeimmo/public_html/test/charts.php on line 95

In this line I have this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE MONTH(st_date) = '$date1' and YEAR(st_date) = '$date2' ";
$sql_sel = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$data = [];
```

what I need to do ? Any help ?

Comment: firefox also gives same error.see console network tab

Comment: 500 does not mean it couldn't find the page. Check your error logs.

Comment: there must be any error in your code that's why you getting `500 Error`. Also check the configurations with your server.

Comment: @tkausl the error_log said : `[10-Jul-2016 17:03:28 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/hipponeimmo/public_html/test/charts.php on line 95
`
In this line I have this : `$sql = "SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE MONTH(st_date) = '$date1' and YEAR(st_date) = '$date2' ";
            $sql_sel = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            $data = [];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the *new* short array syntax `[]` which is available [since PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). You're most likely using PHP 5.3 or less on your Server, so you need to use the old syntax. Use:

```
$data = array();
```

instead of

```
$data = [];
```

and

```
$colors = array( 1 => '8BC34A', 2 => 'FC8213', 3 => '337AB7', 4 => '00CED1', 5 => 'ff5733', 6 => 'd733ff', 7 => 'EEEE00', 8 => '8B4500', 9 => 'FF4500', 10 => 'F08080', 11 => 'B22222', 12 => '8E8E38' );
```

instead of

```
 $colors = [ 1 => '8BC34A', 2 => 'FC8213', 3 => '337AB7', 4 => '00CED1', 5 => 'ff5733', 6 => 'd733ff', 7 => 'EEEE00', 8 => '8B4500', 9 => 'FF4500', 10 => 'F08080', 11 => 'B22222', 12 => '8E8E38' ];
```

Comment: when I make your solution I think it's work but I have a problem, I have some Arrays like this `$colors = [
         1 => '8BC34A',
         2 => 'FC8213',
         3 => '337AB7',
         4 => '00CED1',
         5 => 'ff5733',
         6 => 'd733ff',
         7 => 'EEEE00',
         8 => '8B4500',
         9 => 'FF4500',
         10 => 'F08080',
         11 => 'B22222',
         12 => '8E8E38'
         ];`

How I can change it to your syntax ? (array();)

Comment: I've added it. Essentially, you just need to replace the `[` with `array(` and `]` with `)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot It's wooooooooooooooooooooooooork (y)

Answer (score -1):

I had this similar kind of error few time before. There is a possibility that you have accidentally deleted the file name "webconfig". Ask your service provider if it is the case

Comment: The problem is the others page work, just this page :'(